# WiX: Abort installation if a specific executable is not in the PATH

Tags: wix, dependencies, windows-installer

I'm currently packaging software with WiX that needs Java to run. Therefore I'd like to check during installation if `java.exe` is somewhere in the `PATH` and abort if it could not be found. The solution in http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=23451655 comes close to my needs, but instead of searching the registry, I'd like to look for the dependency in the directories in the `PATH` variable.

Is this easily possible with WiX? If not, is it possible to set the value of a property based on the return value of a custom action. I could then write a batch script that looks for Java and sets the property for the `<Condition>` accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would author an immediate custom action which would do the following:

- grab the value of PATH environment variable. You can use the `[%PATH]` syntax
- parse it by splitting by `;`, iterating and finding the directory in question
- check whether the directory is there and `java.exe` is present there
- set `JAVA_IS_INSTALLED` property to `1` in case it is there, otherwise don't set at all. This can be done as `session["JAVA_IS_INSTALLED"] = 1` with DTF (a framework supplied with WiX Toolset)
- add a `<Condition>` element with `JAVA_IS_INSTALLED` property

NOTE: the custom action should be scheduled before LaunchConditions action and should reside in both sequences (InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Yan's answer I've implemented this functionality like this:

My WiX source contains:

```
<Binary Id="B.CustomActionsScript" SourceFile="CustomActions.js" />
<CustomAction
    Id="CA.runJava"
    BinaryKey="B.CustomActionsScript"
    JScriptCall="runJava"
    Execute="immediate"
    Return="check" />

<Condition Message="The Java Runtime Environment is not installed.">
  Installed OR JAVA_IS_INSTALLED
</Condition>

<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="CA.runJava" Before="LaunchConditions">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CA.runJava" Before="LaunchConditions">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And the `CustomActions.js` contains this function:

```
function runJava() {
  try {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.Run("java -version", 0, true);

    Session.Property("JAVA_IS_INSTALLED") = "1";
  } catch (ex) {
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Instead of looking for `java.exe` in the `PATH` I'm checking if Java is installed by trying to execute it. If Java cannot be executed `Exec` throws an exception and `JAVA_IS_INSTALLED` is never set.